# New command for double coset

Tags: math-mode, macros, delimiters

I defined a new command \doublefaktor to print a double coset of type A\B/C (similar to \faktor which print a quotient A/B) as follows:

```
\newcommand{\doublefaktor}[3]{ {\textstyle #1}\mkern-8mu\diagdown\mkern-5mu^{\textstyle #2}\mkern-5mu\diagup\mkern-8mu{\textstyle #3} }
```

(thanks to previous suggestions here) but I would like to have bigger \diagdown and \diagup in the pdf-printing. How can I do?

Comment: `\big` doesn't take an argument (as in `\big{arg.}`): it is prefixed to a math delimiter, like in `\big(` or `\big|` or `\big\{`.

Comment: Additionally please make your sniplet into a complete example, there are several macros here we do not know the definition of, and thus we cannot test your code without guessing

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik if I write it without \big (so {#1} instead of \big{#1}) it does not return error but the arguments are displayed too small.

Comment: @daleif  \cal and \frak are for \mathcal and \mathfrak, \GL_m(k[s]) is for invertible matrices of size m with polynomial coefficients over k.

Comment: And that is going to help us how? Provide the code, else others cannot test or help with your problem.

Comment: @V.Galgano But that's not how you use `\big`. Should you make your code compilable and your intention with `\big` clearer, someone will point you toward the proper solution. Otherwise, the best we can do is guess.

Comment: @daleif I edited the question. I try to let run the above code with A,B and C and it still does not work, giving to me the same error. As Phelype suggested, by deleting \big in the \newcommand it does not give error anymore, but the letters A,B,C are printed too small.

Comment: What exactly is it you are trying to do? Do you even know what `\big` does? Why are you attempting to apply `\big` to a letter? Perhaps you should start completely over. Explain what the end goal is and then perhaps someone can help you.

Comment: I would like to write a command for a double faktor A\B/C, that is a double quotient defined by left and right action of A and C respectively on B. The command \faktor{A}{B} give the quotient of A/B.

Comment: Then explain that in your question, and perhaps change the title into something that resembles that.

Comment: Ok, thank you both and sorry to have been confusing.

Comment: @daleif I just edited my questions. I solved the previous error by substituting \big by \textstyle.

Comment: Your edit sill not provide MWE (Minimal Working Example, a small but complete document, which reproduce your problem), which would  enable simple testing of your problem.

Comment: You have been told many times now, perhaps you should read https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: `\diagup/down` are non scalable (unless you use font size trickery) you could use `\backslash` and `/` as they are delimiters and `\big` can be applied to them. But the angle is different.

Comment: Since we haven't any information about your document, we re left to guessing. It seems now, that you problem is in preamble of your document. In my math testbed your command works fine (well, result is awful, but this is other story) . So pleas (again), provide MWE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pure guessing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\doublefaktor}[3]{% 
    {\textstyle #1}
    \mkern-4mu\scalebox{1.5}{$\diagdown$}\mkern-5mu^{\textstyle #2}%
    \mkern-4mu\scalebox{1.5}{$\diagup$}\mkern-5mu{\textstyle #3} }

\begin{document}
\[
\doublefaktor{A}{B}{C}
\]
\end{document}
```

Note, above document example is called MWE (Minimal Working Example). It gives after compilation the following result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. For future question how can I display a MWE?

Comment: @V.Galgano, copy content from your LaTeX editor to question window,  than put ``` before and after it. That is.